# Call php function while variable is false

Tags: php

I have a php function that returns a string and I need to display it to some html element until it contains keyword "finished" and also add something like:

```
the string is: <my string here>. Update after 5 (4, 3, 2, 1 sec.)
```

What I have so far:

```
while(!strpos(my_func(), ' finished')) {    
    my_func();
     /*html code goes here*/
    sleep(5); // no reason to call it more often
}
```

But can't figure out how to finish the script. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show how your `my_func()` is implemented.

Comment: Keep in mind that using regular true/false comparison with strpos is a bad idea, because 0 is a possible position. Use === and !== instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
while(strpos($result = my_func(), ' finished') === false) {    
    sleep(5); // no reason to call it more ofthen
}
/*html code goes here, also $result also contains the result value*/
```

But if the result string never contains the string ' finished' it will run forever.

Comment: thanks for you correction but the problem is with the outputting remaining time for the next call.

Comment: You mean you need to output the process to the user while the script is running on the server?

Comment: @Steve.B - I'm not sure what you mean by `outputting remaining time for the next call` . If you like to output something with a 5 second interval. You need to flush your output inside the loop `flush(); sleep(5);`

Comment: @BartHaalstra I mean that I display smthng like: "update after 5 (4, 3, 2, 1 sec.)" -> then output string and repeat it again until fine "finish"

Comment: @Steve.B - You should read more about ajax. This seems like the correct way to achive this.

Comment: You can not do it like this, you need to use javascript to update the html and an ajax call to get the process.